# C one-liner to split a string into lines, tolerating CR, LF, and CR+LF

Tags: c, split, line-endings, one-liner

I was thinking today about how lame it is when programs don't tolerate the three major line break formats (CR, LF, CR+LF), and wondering why so many developers fail to tolerate files from other platforms.

It's simple in JavaScript to split a string into lines regardless of CR, LF, or CR+LF:

```
text.split(/\r\n?|\n/mg)
```

But I was just thinking, maybe this is just difficult enough in other languages that programmers get lazy.  C comes to mind: is it even possible to do this split with a one-liner in C?  ANSI C has no builtin regex library AFAIK, so using a regex would be out of the question, and `strtok` only seems to support a static string delimiter.

But I haven't written any C in a long time...maybe there's a one-liner way to do it that I'm not aware of?

Or, perhaps there are some pitfalls to tolerating mixed line breaks like my above regex does?

Comment: `strtok(text, "\r\n")`

Comment: I, on the other hand was thinking how lame it is that there are 3 ways used to denote a line ending.

Comment: @pmg What does the that have to do with splitting input strings into line?

Comment: C is pretty low level, it doesn't have one-liners for many things.

Comment: @pmg "one-liner" is slang for a simple expression that often fits on one line of the screen. Contrast it with writing a loop.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? Is "no" a good enough answer?

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ - I am sure people there can come up with something interesting!

Comment: According to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html, `strtok` should work fine, as @Barmar has suggested. The second argument is a set of delimiters, not the string on which to delimit. When `\r\n` is encountered, it's treated as a single big delimiter.

Comment: *"wondering why so many developers fail to tolerate files from other platforms"* - your very example of what you are trying to accomplish fails to tolerate files from any platform. This: `text.split(/\r\n?|\n/mg)` splits regardless on any occurrence of `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`. In other words, whichever line ending the file is using, you will parse it wrongly into a different number of lines if it contains other `\r` or `\n` that are not supposed to be line endings.

Comment: @Barmar okay, I had forgotten how `strtok` treats delimiter characters, you can make that an answer if you want

Comment: @MarcoBonelli yes, I didn't think to state that I'm thinking of the common case of user-created text files where `\r` and `\n` aren't meant to be treated differently than line breaks.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I realized exactly what I was overlooking from Barmar's comment so mission accomplished

Comment: @Barmar wait a minute, `strtok(text, "\r\n")` would treat multiple empty lines as a single line break, so it wouldn't be equivalent to the JS code given.  Though for some use cases ignoring empty lines would be just fine.

Comment: That's true, I didn't consider that case.